# How to return the file extension based on the language name from a JSON file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use the JSON file from this repository [Programming Languages Extension](https://gist.github.com/ppisarczyk/43962d06686722d26d176fad46879d41#file-programming_languages_extensions-json-L13) to return the file extensions based on the name of the programming language.

The JSON is like this:

```
[
    {
       "name":"ABAP",
       "type":"programming",
       "extensions":[
          ".abap"
       ]
    },
    {
       "name":"AGS Script",
       "type":"programming",
       "extensions":[
          ".asc",
          ".ash"
       ]
    },
    {
       "name":"AMPL",
       "type":"programming",
       "extensions":[
          ".ampl",
          ".mod"
       ]
    }
]
```

I'm using Python3, but I'm having a hard time to get to the data.

I can get to the point where I print the whole thing, but I can not select the information I want.

```
import json

with open('file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for p in data[0]:
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you'd like to be able to look these up by name, in which case, a nested dictionary would make more sense than a list of dictionaries. You can make one pretty easily with a small dictionary comprehension:

```
In [390]: data_dict = {row['name']: row for row in data}

In [391]: data_dict['AMPL']
Out[391]: {'name': 'AMPL', 'type': 'programming', 'extensions': ['.ampl', '.mod']}

In [392]: data_dict['ABAP']['extensions']
Out[392]: ['.abap']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keys of the JSON to get the data.

The code below will get the extensions, if they are listed, for all the languages with type 'programming'.

```py
import json

with open("Programming_Languages_Extensions.json") as json_file:
  data = json.load(json_file)
  for p in data:
    if p["type"] == "programming":
      try:
        print(f"{p['name']} has extensions {','.join(p['extensions'])}")
      except KeyError:
        print(f"{p['name']} has no extensions listed.")
```

Comment: This code worked well also, but  think the finally block is misplaced. It prints the error message regardless of an error occurring.

Comment: Don't know why I added the `finally` block.:)